# Emulate click on actioncolumn via press button

Tags: extjs

Hello i am have Grid with actioncolumn, and i am want emulate click on actioncolumn when  i press button on keyboard. When i press "Del" in console out this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEl' of undefined.

```
key: 46,
 fn: function(e) {
 Ext.ComponentQuery.query('bookGrid actioncolumn[action=del-book]')[0].getEl().dom.click();
}
```

But when i am emulate click on button all work right:

```
  {
                        key: 13,
                        fn: function(e) {
                            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('bookcont button[name=createbook]')[0].getEl().dom.click();
                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulating DOM events programmatically is generally not a good idea (except for testing purposes). All you may need that artificial click for is to execute an action, to execute the code of the onclick handler.

There is no reason why you couldn't call the function directly without the click simulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you stick a breakpoint in the delete key handler code, what does the line below show in your debugger?

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('bookGrid actioncolumn[action=del-book]')
```

Is it empty? If so then there's a problem with the selector in your component query. Can you share the config for your grid and action column?